# Android-Job/evernote - не запускается

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

Хочу выполнить метод с откладкой и для реализации этой идеи я выбрал библиотеку от Evernote "Android-Job". Проблема в том, что я вроде бы и сделал все как было сказано в документации, но когда запускаю приложение ничего не происходит. Мой код...

Это класс, который отвечает за весь функционал этой библиотеки:

```
public class PollingDataJob extends Job {
    static final String TAG = "polling_data_job_tag";

    @NonNull
    @Override
    protected Result onRunJob(Params params) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onRunJob");
        String query = QueryPreferences.getStoredQuery(getContext());
        String lastResultId = QueryPreferences.getLastResultId(getContext());
        List<GalleryItem> items;

        if (query == null) {
            items = new FlickFetchr().fetchRecentPhotos();
        } else {
            items = new FlickFetchr().searchPhotos(query);
        }
        if (items.size() == 0) {
            return Result.FAILURE;
        }
    String resultId = items.get(0).getId();
    if (resultId.equals(lastResultId)){
        Log.i(TAG, "Got an old result: " + resultId);
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "Got a new result: " + resultId);
    }
    QueryPreferences.setLastResultId(getContext(), resultId);

    Resources resources = getContext().getResources();
    Intent i = PhotoGalleryActivity.newIntent(getContext());
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getContext(), 0, i, 0);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getContext())
            .setTicker(resources.getString(R.string.new_pictures_title))
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_report_image)
            .setContentTitle(resources.getString(R.string.new_pictures_title))
            .setContentText(resources.getString(R.string.new_pictures_text))
            .setContentIntent(pi)
            .build();

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
            NotificationManagerCompat.from(getContext());
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

    return Result.SUCCESS;
}

public static void schedulePeriodic() {
    new JobRequest.Builder(PollingDataJob.TAG)
            .setPeriodic(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(15), TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5))
            .setUpdateCurrent(true)
            .setPersisted(true)
            .setRequiredNetworkType(JobRequest.NetworkType.CONNECTED)
            .build()
            .schedule();
}

public class DemoJobCreator implements JobCreator {

    @Override
    public Job create(String tag) {
        switch (tag) {
            case PollingDataJob.TAG:
                return new PollingDataJob();
            default:
                return null;
        }

    }
}

public final class AddReceiver extends JobCreator.AddJobCreatorReceiver {

    @Override
    protected void addJobCreator(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull JobManager manager) {
        Log.e(TAG, "AddReceiverBroadcast");
        manager.addJobCreator(new DemoJobCreator());
    }
}
```

**Ну и само место запуска метода, который отвечает за весь функционал, который я хочу выполнить в отложенном времени**

```
PollingDataJob.schedulePeriodic();
```

Мне кажется, что вся проблема в том, что не срабатывает слушатель **AddReceiver** и не выполняется строка для запуска JobCreator'a.